# is there a way to manually stretch a polygon?

Tags: qgis, affine-transformation, vertical-transformation

I have this polygon that I want to manually fit and resize(without entering affine numbers, just resizing it with my mouse).
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at the node/vertice tool.

Comment: Edit the layer and use the `Vertex Tool`. You can then select and move vertices, perimeter sides and its central points.

Comment: Do you want only to resize (scale) the feature but keep the shape unaltered? Do you need to rotate the feature as well?

Comment: @Erik The idea is to completely resize and warp the whole polygon.

Comment: @user30184, all that you have mentioned is optional, I do search to manually scale a vector

Comment: In the `advanced digitising toolbox` there's a tool which moves lines - or rathter buffers them manually. As in, you can click on a polygon and grow/shrink linear.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a plug in that is suitable for my demands but is not quite what I was looking for in first place
The plugin is called "Vector Bender" which function as a vector georeferencer

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the Scale Selected Items tool in OpenJUMP would be close to what you want.

[image]

The tool shows the original bounding box of the selected features and user can drag one corner while the opposite corner is fixed. A ghost linework shows the preview of the result and when the mouse button is released the features are scaled.

[image]

QGIS may have a similar tool but if it is unfortunately missing you can make a feature request and use OpenJUMP meanwhile.